# C# How to correctly unload the class from memory?

Tags: c#, dynamic, loading, .net-assembly

I'm developing a solution where a service runs continuously in background, and plugin DLLs can be added/deleted at runtime. The service would load the necessary plugins when needed, run them and unload them. This is the unloading part is what currently gives me trouble: once certain class is successfully loaded first time (variable tc), it never is reloaded, even though the DLL file is updated. I think I am not unloading the class/assembly/appdomain properly, so I'd appreciate some advice for walking this last mile.

Edit: I updated the post to reflect the recent changes in code and explain when exactly the unloading has no effect: the problem does not appear on Linux Ubuntu (via Mono), but it is present on Windows 2008 Server, when I am trying to replace a certain plugin DLL with a newer file version. It seems that .NET framework has cached somewhere the assembly and is happy without reloading it. The DLL file name does not change, but the File Version property is different, so I'd expect the runtime to compare the previously loaded DLL version with the one being loaded and in case of different version numbers use the newer version. If I change the code slightly to load the assembly from a DLL file with different name, the reloading happens as expected.

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

namespace TestMonoConsole
{
    public interface ITestClass
    {
        void Talk();
    }
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            string pluginPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

            string classAssembly = "TestClass";
            string className = "TestMonoConsole.TestClass";
            string command = "";
            do
            {
                try
                {
                    System.AppDomain domain = System.AppDomain.CreateDomain(classAssembly);
                    string pluginAssemblyFile = pluginPath + "/" + classAssembly + ".dll";
                    System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(pluginAssemblyFile, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252), false);
                    byte[] b = new byte[reader.BaseStream.Length];
                    reader.BaseStream.Read(b, 0, System.Convert.ToInt32(reader.BaseStream.Length));
                    domain.Load(b);
                    reader.Close();
                    ITestClass tc = (ITestClass) Activator.CreateInstance(domain, classAssembly, className).Unwrap();
                    tc.Talk();
                    System.AppDomain.Unload(domain);
                }
                catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine (String.Format("Error loading plugin: assembly {0} not found", classAssembly));
                }
                command = Console.ReadLine();
            } while (command == "");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any exception get caught or log in the Event Viewer. If yes then please post the exception here

Comment: I read somewhere that a common trick is to generate a new application domain and terminate it when you don't need it anymore

Comment: No exceptions caught nor anything in the Event Viewer.

Answer (score 3):

You are creating the types directly into the host domain. You need to specify the domain when using Activator.CreateInstance per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224132(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Thanks, using Activator.CreateInstance(AppDomain, String, String) actually fixed the problem, but, surprisingly, only on my Ubuntu (via Mono), but not on the Windows 2003 Server (actual deployment OS).

Comment: Note that works for Framework but not .NET Core/5+

Answer (score 1):

You are instantiating the plugin types within your own AppDomain. After implementing plugin frameworks several times, I highly suggest looking into using MEF(managed extensibility framework) as a solution since it handles these common problems of code isolation. If you don't want MEF, one way to do this is by implementing a "Remote Control" class which would act as the communicator between app domains. You could call a method on your remote class that would instantiate and run the code within the secondary app domain.

[MEF Documentation](http://mef.codeplex.com/)

Comment: I don't believe MEF offers app-domain isolation. The framework you're thinking about is MAF - which I've referred to below. MEF can, however be used with MAF to provide a very extensible app-plugin framework.

Comment: Thanks, I'll see if MEF suits my needs. I really am not up to reinventing the wheel, however, when I have a code that "almost works" on my hands, it is always nice to see it fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Also, instead of re-inventing this mechanism, you can utilize the Managed Add-In Framework (MAF, System.AddIn) to do this for you. Look [here](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/9396/creating-extensible-applications-with-maf/) for a quickstart.

Answer (score 0):

Types and assemblies cannot be unloaded from AppDomain.
So you need to create new AppDomain, load types, do all the stuff, and then unload that domain.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404279.aspx), the CLR does not use shadow copying by default. You could try to enable it by following these steps:

1. Create an [AppDomainSetup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9hc77a1s).
2. In the AppDomainSetup instance set ShadowCopyFiles to true.
3. In the AppDomainSetup instance set ShadowCopyFilesDirectories to the directory path(s) that contain the assemblies you want to be able to ovewrite at run time. This could simply be the directory where the plug-in assembly is located.
4. In the AppDomainSetup instance set everything else according to your needs.
5. Use one of the overloads of [AppDomain.CreateAppDomain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.createdomain) that take an AppDomainSetup as an argument.
6. Try to replace the plug-in assembly.

The fact that it works on Mono and not on CLR (Windows) could mean that the [CLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Infrastructure) does not specify if shadow copying should be enabled by default.